# Dynamic instantiation of classes using a variable that stores de class name

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to instantite classes dinamically, using a variable to store the name of the class to instantiate.

```
use DefaultBundle\Form\CategoryType;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $classname = 'CategoryType::class';

        //$form = $this->createForm(CategoryType::class);

        $form = $this->createForm($classname);
```

But I get this error:

> Could not load type "CategoryType::class"

As you can imagine, I don't have any problem using the commented line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes.

```
$classname = CategoryType::class;
```

Otherwise it is passing the string literal `CategoryType::class` instead of the class name

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need the first part of the class name to be variable, in order to use the same code for different classes. I have tried this: `$classname =  $variable . '::class'` but it doesn't work

Comment: Stop putting quotes ;-)

Comment: I have now this: `$classname = 'DefaultBundle\Form\CategoryType';` and it is working ok